# Google Data Studio / Missing data

Tags: looker-studio

[image]

Hello great teachers

I'm trying to blend the data on Google data studio.
Then there is missing data, that's been caused by join key, on the right but in the source data(on the left side) there is no missing join key. 
Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug.  Do you have any charts associated with the blended data source now? If not, remove the blended data source, and do it again.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. It was just a bug. Thank you very much